# XF CarouselViewRenderer iOS to show a preview of the next and previous views

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have to implement a carouselview with a preview to the left and the right of the previous and next views on the slider in `Xamarin.Forms`. I have accomplished this on `Android` by using the `ViewRenderer` of the carouselview package `CarouselView.FormsPlugin` and now I have to do the same for `iOS`.

This is how it looks on Android and how it should look like on iOS.

[image]

On Android I did this using the following code:

```
// InterPageSpacing BP
var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
int interPageSpacing = int.Parse(Math.Round(Element.InterPageSpacing * metrics.Density).ToString());

viewPager.SetPadding(interPageSpacing, 0, interPageSpacing, 0);
viewPager.SetClipToPadding(false);
viewPager.PageMargin = int.Parse(Math.Round(interPageSpacing * 0.25).ToString());
```

In the `SetNativeView()` method of the renderer

The big problem is that in iOS there is no padding, clipToPadding and pageMargin on a UIView.

I tried using the `Bounds`, `LayoutMargins` and `ClipToBounds`, but that didn't work.
Also I tried setting the width of the frame from the `UIView` and setting the padding and margin of each individual item in the carouselview, but that didn't work either.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You can create a new `UIPageViewController ` with spacing and replace the original one. refer to [the comment by shnaz](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView/issues/11).

Comment: If I do that it does not give the result I need. By setting the InterPageSpacing in the package (the way you described) it adds space between the pages outside the screen.

Comment: @FabianClaasen Did you get the  answer , If it is could you please explain the android and ios code

Comment: @AswathyKR No unfortunately I have not been able to accomplish this and it is no longer needed as the customer chose for something else.

Comment: Hello, even though @FabianClaasen you no longer needed it does anyone have an idea on how to get this working